# Kendo Hierarchical Grids reload data of first opened details grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I got 2 grids in hierarchy:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
            .Name("Obj")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ResID).Title("ID").Width(50);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Organization).EditorTemplateName("DropdownSupplier").ClientTemplate("#= Organization.Value #").Title("Supplier").Width(160);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ResourceType).EditorTemplateName("DropdownResourceType").ClientTemplate("#=ResourceType.Value#").Title("Resource Type").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ResourceName).Title("Description").Width(150);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity).EditorTemplateName("Double").Title("Quantity").Width(120);
                columns.Bound(p => p.QuantityUOM).EditorTemplateName("DropdownQuantityUOM").ClientTemplate("#=QuantityUOM.Value#").Title("Quantity UOM").Width(80);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Area).ClientTemplate("#= Area.Value #").EditorTemplateName("DropdownAreas").Title("Area of Operation").Width(120);
                columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeSmaller").Title("Order Date").Format("{0:" + format + "}").Width(170);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ETA).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeSmaller").Title("ETA").Format("{0:" + format + "}").Width(170);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Arrived).EditorTemplateName("Checkbox").Title("Arrived").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= Arrived ? checked='checked' : '' # onchange='UpdateResourceArrived(this, \"#=ResourceID#\")' ></input>").Width(60);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Status).ClientTemplate("#=Status.Value#").EditorTemplateName("DropdownStatus").Title("Status").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.IsTactical).EditorTemplateName("Checkbox").Title("Tactical").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsTactical ? checked='checked' : '' # ></input>").Width(60);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ResourceID).Title("Resource").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:1px;" }).Width(1).Hidden(true);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
            {
                //toolbar.Save();
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Navigatable()
            .Filterable()
            .Events(e =>
            {
                e.Edit("removeValidation");
                e.FilterMenuInit("initCheckboxFilter");
                e.Change("onSelectedRowChange");
                e.DataBound("ResourcesDataBound");

            })
            .Excel(x => x.FileName("ICS_201-4_IncidentResources.xlsx").AllPages(true).Filterable(true).ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Grid")))
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Height("auto"))
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .Groupable()
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
                    .Events(events =>
                    {
                        events.Error("error_handler");
                    })
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ResourceID);
                model.Field(p => p.ResID).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p=>p.Arrived).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.Status).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultStatus"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
                model.Field(p => p.Area).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultAreas"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
                model.Field(p => p.Organization).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultSupplier"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
                model.Field(p => p.ResourceType).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultResourceType"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
                model.Field(p => p.QuantityUOM).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultQuantityUOM"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
            })
            .Read(read =>
                        read.Action("Resources_Read", "ICSForms")
                            .Data("filterByPeriod")
                 )
            .Create("Resources_Create", "ICSForms")
            .Update(x=>x.Action("Resources_Update", "ICSForms"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Resources_Destroy", "ICSForms")).AutoSync(true)
            )
            .ClientDetailTemplateId("rTemplate")
    )
```

and:

```
 <script type="text/kendo" id="rTemplate">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
            .Name("childObj")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ResID).Title("ID").Width(50);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Organization).ClientTemplate("\\#=Organization.Value\\#").Title("Supplier").Width(160);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ResourceType).ClientTemplate("\\#=ResourceType.Value\\#").Title("Resource Type").EditorTemplateName("DropdownResourceType").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ResourceName).Title("Description").Width(150);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity).EditorTemplateName("Double").Title("Quantity").Width(120);
                columns.Bound(p => p.QuantityUOM.Value).EditorTemplateName("DropdownQuantityUOM").ClientTemplate("#=QuantityUOM.Value#").Title("Quantity UOM").Width(80);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Area).ClientTemplate("\\#=Area.Value\\#").EditorTemplateName("DropdownAreas").Title("Area of Operation").Width(120);
                columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeSmaller").Title("Order Date").Width(170).Format("{0:" + DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAP.Helpers.IApplicationOptionsProvider>().GetDataFormat(false, true) + "}"); ;
                columns.Bound(p => p.ETA).EditorTemplateName("DateTimeSmaller").Title("ETA").Width(170).Format("{0:" + DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAP.Helpers.IApplicationOptionsProvider>().GetDataFormat(false, true) + "}"); ;
                columns.Bound(p => p.Arrived).EditorTemplateName("Checkbox").Title("Arrived").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' \\#= Arrived ? checked='checked' : '' \\#  onchange='UpdateResourceArrived(this, \"#=ResourceID#\")' ></input>").Width(60);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Status).ClientTemplate("\\#=Status.Value\\#").EditorTemplateName("DropdownStatus").Title("Status").Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.IsTactical).EditorTemplateName("Checkbox").Title("Tactical").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' \\#= IsTactical ? checked='checked' : '' \\# ></input>").Width(60);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ResourceID).Title("Resource").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:1px;width:1px;max-width:1px;" }).Width(1).Hidden(true);
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Navigatable()
            .Filterable()
            .Events(e =>
            {
                e.Edit("removeValidation");
                e.FilterMenuInit("initCheckboxFilter");
                e.Change("onSelectedRowChange");
            })
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Height(120))
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .Groupable()
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ResourceID);
                model.Field(p => p.ResourceID).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.ResID).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.Status).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultStatus"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
                model.Field(p => p.Area).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultAreas"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
                model.Field(p => p.Organization).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultSupplier"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
                model.Field(p => p.ResourceType).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultResourceType"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
                model.Field(p => p.QuantityUOM).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultQuantityUOM"] as MinifiedKeyValueModel);
            })
                .Read(read =>
                            read.Action("ResourcesChildren_Read", "ICSForms",
                                     new { resourceID = "#=ResourceID#" }))
                .Update(update => update.Action("Resources_Update", "ICSForms"))
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Resources_Destroy", "ICSForms")).AutoSync(true)
            ).ToClientTemplate()
        )

    </script>
```

The problem is that if I open the details of one of the rows and I see everything that has that parent (so far so good) and I open another details grid it opens an empty one and the first one refreshes its data with the ids of the second opened element.

I researched this issue, but I couldn't find similar occurrences. Any help solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a unique name for every instance of a grid.

```
<script type="text/kendo" id="rTemplate">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
        .Name("childObj_#=ResID#") //Assuming ResID is the parent model's ID (I think #=id# would work as well if you have set the Id in the model)
[...]
```

If you use `$("#childObj")` anywhere, you will have to refactor that somehow.

Comment: Oh.... yeah it's that easy huh? :D I feel so dumb right now :D thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I knew the answer because I did the same mistake when I started using kendo widgets :)